# Selenium adding items from a Web element list to a string array list

Tags: java, arrays, selenium-webdriver

I'm doing some automated testing and I'm trying to save some items from a web element list to a string array, there should be some parsing involved but I'm not sure how, see code snippet below

```
public void I_should_see_the_following_folders(DataTable expectedData) throws Throwable {
    int tbl1; int tbl2;
    List<List<String>> featureTable = expectedData.raw();
    WebElement folders = driver.findElement(By.id("folders"));
    List <WebElement> emailFolders = folders.findElements(By.className("folder-name"));

    List<String> foo = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (List<String> featuresList : expectedData.raw())
        foo.add(featuresList.get(0));

        tbl1 = emailFolders.size();
        tbl2 = featureTable.size();

    List<String> webList = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i=0;i<tbl1;i++){
        webList.add(emailFolders.get(0));
    }



}
```

what I'm trying to do is take a datatable list of items, convert it into a string array and then take a list of items from the webpage and also store it into a string array and then compare each array to determine if the elements are present and are the same in not particular order.

I think I got the data table array list to work, but need some help with the web elements array list.

Thanks!!!

Comment: Well what information from the WebElement you want? Do you want it's `text`? Some other attribute?

Comment: I was trying to get the text, then do a string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using following sample code, change xpath/data accordingly

```
List<WebElement> resultList = _driver.findElements(By.xpath("//img[contains(@src,'tab-close.png')]/preceding-sibling::span[@class='tab-name ng-binding']"));
        for (WebElement resultItem : resultList){
           String tabname=resultItem.getText();
           if(resultItem.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("Dashboard")){
           GlobalFunctions.clickOnButtonCustomised(false, _driver, By.xpath("//span[@class='tab-name ng-binding' and contains(text(),'"+tabname+"')]/following-sibling::img[contains(@src,'tab-close.png')]"), "");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
for (int i=0; i<tbl1; i++)
    webList.add(emailFolders.get(0));
```

To this:

```
for (WebElement emailFolder : emailFolders)
    webList.add(emailFolder.getAttribute(XXX));
```

Then, replace `XXX` with the name of the attribute which stores the actual folder name.

A few examples:

- For `<tag><class="folder-name" id="folder1"></tag>`, replace `XXX` with `"id"`
- For `<tag><class="folder-name" value="folder1"></tag>`, replace `XXX` with `"value"`
- For `<tag><class="folder-name">folder1</tag>`, replace `XXX` with `"innerHTML"`

BTW, instead of `getAttribute("innerHTML")`, you can simply use `getText()`.

Answer (score 0):

There may be an easier way to convert a List of WebElements to String[] array, but this generic method works -

```
//  iterate through all elements adding to array we are returning
public static String[] listToStringArray(List<WebElement> inList) {
    String[] outArray = new String[inList.size()];  // instantiate Array

    for (int i = 0; i < inList.size(); i++) {
        outArray[i] = inList.get(i).getText();
        }
    }
    return outArray;
}
```